# Liquid haskell creating a new bytestring with PS

Tags: haskell, liquid-haskell

I'm making some bindings to C from Haskell, and trying to make it safer with LiquidHaskell. I'm having some trouble with specifying the length of a bytestring in the LH type annotation.

I have an enhanced ByteString type in LiquidHaskell that includes its length:

```
{-@ type ByteString Blen = {v:B.ByteString | bslen v == Blen} @-}
```

I am getting the following error when I run Liquidhaskell:

```
**** RESULT: UNSAFE ************************************************************


 /home/t/liquidproblem/Main.hs:47:3-22: Error: Liquid Type Mismatch

 47 |   Bi.PS foreignPtr 0 l
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   Inferred type
     VV : {v : Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString | 0 <= bslen v
                                                     && bslen v == stringlen v}

   not a subtype of Required type
     VV : {VV : Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString | bslen VV == l}

   In Context
     l : {l : GHC.Types.Int | l >= 0}
```

Line 47 is:

```
44 {-@ makeBs :: ForeignPtr Word8 -> l:NonNeg -> ByteString l @-}
45 makeBs :: F.ForeignPtr F.Word8 -> Int -> B.ByteString
46 makeBs foreignPtr l =
47   Bi.PS foreignPtr 0 l
```

(I know this seems a bit of a silly function, but it got put in because the debugging process was to factor out bits and put LH annotations on them till I found the problem.)

The relevant imports are:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Internal as Bi
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Foreign as F
```

The LH NonNeg type is

```
{-@ type NonNeg = {i:Int | i >= 0} @-}
```

Comment: I'm no LH expert but, the type of `makeBs` promises that if we have a `ForeignPtr Word8` we can make a bytestring out of it having any nonnegative length. Don't we need to require that the pointer indeed points to that many bytes? Just a guess.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like a good idea.  I'm thinking maybe something like {-@ type LHForeignPtr L = {f:ForeignPtr | len f == L} @-}.  But how do you get the number of bytes that the pointer points to? (I'm no LH expert either)

Answer (score 1):

LiquidHaskell doesn't know that the `ByteString` returned by `makeBs` has length `l`, and it can't prove that from the information available to it.

You know it will because you know that the third argument to the `PS` constructor is the length. So at this point you have two (or possibly one) options:

1. You can try to tell LH what you know about the `PS` constructor, and give it an annotation like 
   `{-@ Bi.PS :: _ -> _ -> l:NonNeg -> ByteString l @-}`. I tried this and it didn't quite work because there are internal GHC types in the signature of `PS` that LH doesn't seem so good at handling. YMMV. Or, you can:
2. Forget about annotating `PS` and mark your own function with `assume`: `{-@ assume makeBs :: ForeignPtr Word8 -> l:NonNeg -> ByteString l @-}`. Of course, this gets riskier if the function marked with `assume` gets any bigger—silly though it may seem, you might want to keep `makeBs` around if you go this route.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I'd forgotten about this question, but when I get time I will have another look at this.